Is there a way to make tasks/threads that execute in multiple stages?
I am trying to figure out how to improve my use of C# and solve a few problems in my code (which is the subject of a much more panicked question I posted earlier and which I will likely take down for its lack of clarity). However, I think this deserves a more general description from the top:
I am coding a C# application which interfaces with an Arduino over a serial port, which controls two servo motors. What I am trying to figure out is how to make a thread, async method, or other system, to stop and wait at specific parts of a method for the commands it sends to the arduino to complete.
In my current structure,
The C# program communicates with the arduino by receiving a string from a SerialPort serialPort . When new data is received, the serialPort.DataReceived  event calls the method serialPort_ReceivedData . This method receives the new data and checks it for a number of significant phrases:
public static void serialPort_ReceivedData(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
SerialPort spL = (SerialPort)sender;
byte[] buf = new byte[spL.BytesToRead];
spL.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
newDataContent = $"{System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf)}";
Console.WriteLine($"Received: {newDataContent}");
string[] thingsToParse = newDataContent.Split('\n'); //each command is separated by a newline character, so in case multiple commands are sent close to each other, we separate and iterate through parsing them

            foreach (string thing in thingsToParse)
            {
                switch (thing)
                {
                    case string c when c.Contains("Home done"):
                        homed = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("homed true");
                        break;
    
                    case string a when a.Contains("X done"):
                        xDone = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("xDone true");
                        break;
    
                    case string b when b.Contains("Y done"):
                        yDone = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("yDone true");
                        break;
    
                    default: break; //do nothing
                }
            }
        }

For example, the user selects the "Home" command in the user interface which sets up a Thread HomeThread = new Thread(() => Home());, which runs this method:
public static void Home()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Beginning Home");
    WriteMyCommand(2,0,serialPort); //this method sends the "Home" command to the arduino.
    while(!homed)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Still homing...");
        Thread.Sleep(250);
    }
    xDone = false; //ensures x and y done flags that are occasionally triggered by Homing are reset before backoff.
    yDone = false;
    Console.WriteLine("Initial homing completed, beginning backoff");
    WriteMyCommand(0, backoff, serialPort);
    WriteMyCommand(1, backoff, serialPort);
    while(!(xDone && yDone))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Still backing off...");
        Thread.Sleep(250);   
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Backoff completed, unlocking.");
    ready = true;
}

This system is adequate, but not necessarily good. It doesn't handle interruptions well and takes up a lot of memory, especially if multiple instances of the HomeThread are accidentally called.
I've tried alternate methods of temporarily pausing code execution, such as awaiting a dummy task (see previous question on topic if it's still up), WaitOne();, and I've attempted to await  events. I'm sure all of these methods would have worked eventually but my coding skill is currently not up to snuff with these more complicated tricks. (For reference, I'm still working on understanding how to make my own events and EventHandlers to solve this problem).
Does anyone have any more robust or efficient suggestions for handling this problem? I would really appreciate any and all advice.
EDIT, 9 Aug. 2024:
I have built a minimum reproducible example after much request.
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml.Linq;

/* This is a minimum reproducible example of my arduino control-response code, to be adapted from a console application into a code library for a windows forms app.
 * 
 * This is the variation of the code which uses sleep-loops to delay thread execution until a specific arduino signal is produced.
 * 
 * My objective over the past few months has been finding a less-resource-intensive alternative to these sleep loops, as this UI program needs to be able to run while
 * other processes are running on the computer in the background.
 * (This is to be installed on a computer which controls large industrial machinery, it cannot fail and cannot be inefficient. The full application interfaces
 * with the control software for the machine.)
 * 
 */

namespace MinRepExample080924
{
    class Program
    {

        const int thisDeviceInteger = 1;

        public static string newDataContent = string.Empty;
        public static DateTime newDataDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;

        public static SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM9", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        public static bool ready, homed, xDone, yDone, stopped = false;

        static void Main()
        {
            bool good = false;
            while (!good) 
            {
                try { serialPort.Open(); }
                finally
                {
                    if (serialPort.IsOpen) //did it open
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("serialPort Open:\n\n---\n");
                        good = true;
                    }
                    else //the gate is not open
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("serialPort did not open.");
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                }
            }

            serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            serialPort.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort_ReceivedData);

            Console.WriteLine("Beginning COMMANDS");

            Console.WriteLine("\nInput a command:\n-\tH - Home\n-\tX - Move X\n-\tY - Move Y\n-\tS - STOP\n-\tR - Read current serial info\n-\tG - Status report\n\nOr press anything else to exit."); //menu desc.

            bool exitCommands = false; //resets exit command for redundancy's sake.
            while (exitCommands == false)
            { 

                Console.Write(">>"); //user input prompt
                char cmdType = Console.ReadLine().ToLower().ToCharArray()[0]; //extracts the relevant command signifier character. see above list.
                string input = string.Empty;

                switch (cmdType) //user command interface
                {
                    case 'h': //home command.

                        Console.WriteLine("sending command Home();");

                        // I can either use:
                        // Task.Run(Home);
                        // or
                        Thread HomeThread = new Thread(Home);

                        Console.WriteLine("breaking switch statement at Home();");

                        break;

                    case 'x':
                        //handles x positional input
                        Console.Write("Input X position\n>>");
                        input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                        if (input == string.Empty) { input = "0"; }
                        int x = int.Parse(input);
                        //end x pos input

                        Console.WriteLine("sending command MoveX(x);");

                        // Task-based:
                        // Task.Run(() => MoveX(x));

                        // Thread-based (older version):
                        Thread moveXThread = new Thread(() => MoveX(x));

                        Console.WriteLine("breaking switch statement at MoveX(x);");

                        break;

                    case 'y':
                        //handles y positional input
                        Console.Write("Input Y position\n>>");
                        input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                        if (input == string.Empty) { input = "0"; }
                        int y = int.Parse(input);
                        //end y pos input

                        Console.WriteLine("sending command MoveY(y);");

                        //Task-based:
                        //Task.Run(() => MoveY(y)); //instances async MoveY and awaits the data response. Passes off handling to the async method.

                        //Thread-based (older version):
                        Thread moveYThread = new Thread(() => MoveY(y));

                        Console.WriteLine("breaking switch statement at MoveY(y);");

                    
                        break;

                    case 's':

                        Console.WriteLine("sending command STOP();");

                        //Task-based:
                        //Task.Run(STOP);

                        //Thread-based (older verions):
                        Thread stopThread = new Thread(STOP);

                        Console.WriteLine("breaking switch statement at MoveY(y);");

                        break;

                    case 'r':

                        Console.WriteLine("beginning read");

                        Console.WriteLine($"{newDataContent} | {newDataDateTime.ToString("HH:mm:dd.ffff")}");

                        Console.WriteLine("ending read");

                        break;

                    case 'g':

                        Console.WriteLine("Input value to send");

                        Console.Write("Input value to send\n>>");
                        input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                        if (input == string.Empty) { Console.WriteLine("Exiting."); break; }

                        WriteMyMessage(input, serialPort);

                        break;

                    case '\0':
                        Console.WriteLine("Exiting command menu.");
                        exitCommands = true;
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Exiting command menu.");
                        exitCommands = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Exiting commands.");
        }
        public static void serialPort_ReceivedData(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) //event that parses incoming data into its commands when new data arrives, and sets bools high to permit their associated tasks to pass through.
        {
            SerialPort spL = (SerialPort)sender;
            byte[] buf = new byte[spL.BytesToRead];
            spL.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            newDataContent = $"{System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf)}";
            Console.WriteLine($"Received: {newDataContent}");
            string[] thingsToParse = newDataContent.Split('\n'); //each command is separated by a newline character, so in case multiple commands are sent close to each other, we separate and iterate through parsing them

            foreach (string thing in thingsToParse)
            {
                switch (thing)
                {
                    case string c when c.Contains("Home done"):
                        homed = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("homed true");
                        break;

                    case string a when a.Contains("X done"):
                        xDone = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("xDone true");
                        break;

                    case string b when b.Contains("Y done"):
                        yDone = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("yDone true");
                        break;

                    case string d when d.Contains("Stopped"):
                        stopped = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("stopped true");
                        break;

                    default: break; //do nothing if there's nothing.
                }
            }
        }

        public static int backoff = 15000; //backoff step distance.

        ///<summary>
        /// This method commands the arduino on the other end of the <see cref="serialPort"/> to begin its homing sequence.
        /// Once the homing sequence is triggered, the method waits until <see cref="homed"/> == true, then performs the backoff sequence.
        /// Then, it sets <see cref="ready"/> = true.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Home()
        {
            ready = false;
            homed = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Beginning Home");
            WriteMyCommand(2, 0, serialPort); //this method sends the "Home" command to the arduino.
            while (!homed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Still homing...");
                Thread.Sleep(250);
            }
            xDone = false; //ensures x and y done flags that are occasionally triggered by Homing are reset before backoff.
            yDone = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Initial homing completed, beginning backoff");
            WriteMyCommand(0, backoff, serialPort);
            WriteMyCommand(1, backoff, serialPort);
            while (!(xDone && yDone))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Still backing off...");
                Thread.Sleep(250);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Backoff completed, unlocking.");
            ready = true;
        }

        ///<summary>
        /// This method commands the arduino on the other end of the <see cref="serialPort"/> to move the X-motor to position <paramref name="x"/>, then waits for callback.
        /// </summary>
        public static void MoveX(int x)
        {
            xDone = false;
            if (!homed) { return; }
            WriteMyCommand(0, x, serialPort);
            Console.WriteLine("awaiting ...");
            while (!xDone)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Still moving...");
                Thread.Sleep(250);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("...xDone Received");
        }

        ///<summary>
        /// This method commands the arduino on the other end of the <see cref="serialPort"/> to move the Y-motor to position <paramref name="y"/>, then waits for callback.
        /// </summary>
        public static void MoveY(int y)
        {
            yDone = false;
            if (!homed) { return; }
            WriteMyCommand(1, y, serialPort);
            Console.WriteLine("awaiting yDone...");
            while (!yDone)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Still moving...");
                Thread.Sleep(250);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("...yDone Received.");
        }

        ///<summary>
        /// This method commands the arduino on the other end of the <see cref="serialPort"/> to immediately cease all movement, then waits for callback.
        /// </summary>
        public static void STOP()
        {
            stopped = false;
            WriteMyCommand(4, 0, serialPort);
            Console.WriteLine("STOPPING...");
            while (!stopped)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Still moving...");
                Thread.Sleep(250);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("...RESPONSE STOP.");
            homed = false;
            ready = false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function prints a string <paramref name="inputString"/> to the serial port <paramref name="serialPort"/> using byte by byte ASCII encoding.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="inputString"></param>
        /// <param name="serialPort"></param>
        public static void WriteMyMessage(string inputString, SerialPort serialPort)
        {
            byte[] MyMessage = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputString); //encodes string into an ASCII format byte array using inbuilt GetBytes() function.
            serialPort.Write(MyMessage, 0, MyMessage.Length); //sends it to the serial port.
            Console.WriteLine(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(MyMessage)); //converts it back to string for sanity check.
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function instructs the arduino by assembling and sending a string to the <paramref name="serialPort"/> with <see cref="WriteMyMessage(string, SerialPort)"/>.<br/>
        /// This instruction is generated using the device number (1), the <paramref name="command"/> which is an integer specifying the command type, and a <paramref name="value"/> <br/>
        /// to be sent with the command if relevant. The value defaults to 000000.
        /// <para/>
        /// A simple way to get a <paramref name="command"/> with attached <paramref name="value"/> formatted and sent to the <paramref name="serialPort"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="command"></param>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        /// <param name="serialPort"></param>
        public static void WriteMyCommand(int command, int? value, SerialPort serialPort) //easy shorthand way to get things in command format and sent
        {
            if (value == null) { value = 0; } //defaults value to zero for ease of reading and to catch any errors.
            string inputMessage = $"{thisDeviceInteger:D1}{command:D1}{value:D6}"; //concactonates the string together using special formatting. (D# stands for "digits" and the number of digits)
            WriteMyMessage(inputMessage, serialPort);
        }
    }
}

Thank you all for your help so far, I was assigned this project with very little experience in this field, and am trying my best to learn. You have been very helpful!
I would like to make my problem a little more clear now after some tinkering: How should I replace the while-Thread.Sleep loops? Ideally, I would like to use tasks. For example, I would like to break up the process of homing the arduino into a "Homing command", waiting, then "backoff" stage, then "backoff reported successfully". I've been researching ways to do this but ended up in a complete tizzy, trying to use functions I do not understand. Thank you.

wish i could help you.. seems like there is more code you need to share.

if you have multiple threads firing Home() i can see thread safety issues in doing that.. you are setting vars in this Home that another incoming message could change.. firing off a new thread every time is likely a memory/performance hit.. don't see why you need that from what you've shared.. especially knowing that a com port is gonna need synchronized handling

firing off await or more threads is just gonna kill performance..

Sounds like a Producer/Consumer pattern would be how you'd want to handle, perhaps a set of worker threads ready to run...  show more code.  show the problem you are trying to solve.

For parallel programming I would suggest to try CotinueWith() or with threads with new Thread() and by setting isBackground to false, more info here

Maybe your "stages" should instead be "states"? Seems like you need to learn about state machines (aka finite state automata). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

It would be really awesome if you posted a [mcve]. There is so much code missing that it makes it hard to give you a decent response.

Hi, all. Thank you for the advice. To clarify:

Yes, I have very little idea of what I am doing and absolutely am grasping at straws. Thank you sawdust for the link to the finite state machine wiki, I'll try my best to absorb the info.
I am having difficulty creating a minimum reproducible example because my code is scattered between prototypes, my boss doesn't even want me on this website because it could unintentionally leak information about the product, and it requires an arduino to send back info via the SerialPort. I'm not sure what a minimum reproducible example would look like.


Tomorrow I will try to upload a minimum reproducible example, and will attempt to rewrite my original post around it.

Additionally, @oceano1970526, I'll investigate the ContinueWith() integration. This is helpful, but is it possible for a continuation to be triggered only when a specific signal is received? Thank you.

@CameronHadland .... I had some issues with the closures scope inside of the continueWith(). You can try the trigger there and see if it helps? I moved away from this for a while now.

I put an answer on your original "panicked question" since it has 5 upvotes (including mine).

You are making a concurrent program without taking concurrency into consideration.
As I understand to me your program does this:

listen to events from ardoino
act on event with different logic for each event asynchronously
update state variables to know when you can conclude some of your operations such as home, done

you have several issues:
you open threads without regard to already running threads, a problematic situation can occur such as:

start home action
xDone
start another home action, xDone=false again
yDone (from original home)
xDone (from new home)
second home action finishes without ACTUALLY being done

In terms of memory, you are starting threads without regard to your system specs, a server with 64cores can open a lot of threads which will all be effective
a small VM/pod/laptop with a few cores, will stop gaining performance and start loosing performance with more threads being open quite fast. more threads only help as long as there are available non busy threads to take the work and if the work is truly async.
luckily C# has a feature called TaskPools which is the recommended feature for your use case I'd say, basically Tasks are asynchronous operations which are then ran by a TaskPool, a pool of task executing workers, which C# automatically manages how many threads pull tasks from this pool according to what is most efficient. this will probably help with your performance and resources issues.
for your correct code issue, To me it seems that while your different operations can be asynchronous, there cant be multiple of the same operation running at once. this is assuming only one "home" operation can run on your ardoino at once.
So in your code you must make sure that only one operation of each kind is running at once.
you can do this with locks within the functions, lock at the start of the function, unlock at the end, to verify only one at a time will run.
example of the concepts I talked about:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    private static int sharedResource = 0;
    private static readonly object lockObject = new object();

    // Semaphores to ensure only one instance of each action is running at a time
    private static SemaphoreSlim semaphoreAction1 = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    private static SemaphoreSlim semaphoreAction2 = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => RunActionWithSemaphore(Action1, semaphoreAction1)));
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => RunActionWithSemaphore(Action2, semaphoreAction2)));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        Console.WriteLine($"Final value of shared resource: {sharedResource}");
    }

    static async Task RunActionWithSemaphore(Func<Task> action, SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            await action();
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    static async Task Action1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100); // Simulate some async work

            lock (lockObject)
            {
                sharedResource += 1;
                Console.WriteLine($"Action1 incremented shared resource to {sharedResource}");
            }
        }
    }

    static async Task Action2()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(150); // Simulate some async work

            lock (lockObject)
            {
                sharedResource += 2;
                Console.WriteLine($"Action2 incremented shared resource to {sharedResource}");
            }
        }
    }
}


Thank you very much for the example code, I appreciate your patience with my lack of example code. This sort of framework is exactly what I needed, though I have one question about implementing a feature. If I needed a task to wait for a specific response from the serial port from the arduino, what should I do? Should I split it into two separate tasks, or have some kind of blocking/waiting functionality? Thank you.

@CameronHadland It's really down to your project definition, blocking until you receive a response is far simpler to implement and will leave less room for issues to occur. so if you dont need anything else to occur while that happens that perfect.
If you do want stuff to keep running than you send an initial "start" request and on both sides keep running, when the ardoino finishes it will send the "done" request and you process it, its not very complicated but an async program will always be a bit more complex so only do it if its required, but dont fear it.
